# On IBM Metadata Asset Manager, can I select specific tables from metadata schemas to share to a repository?

Tags: ibm-information-server

I have imported metadata on IBM Metadata Asset Manager that contains over 15,000 tables distributed among 4 schemas. However, I do not require all of them to be shared to the repository. Trying to share all the tables is causing my server to (obviously and reasonably) choke up. Is there any way I can select specific tables from the different imported schemas in the metadata, to share to the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was only resolved when I created a new Import Area. Once the table are selected, only those are visible unless a new table is added to the directory.